# export and import a Typescript Type alias from .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to have a file such as `vue-number.d.ts` with a declaration along the lines of:

```js
export type vueNumber = number | '';
```

and then be able to use the type alias across multiple typescript modules.

If I use the above code, the import statement has `'vue-number.d.ts' is not a module`

How can I export and import a typescript type, which I can then use as if it was declared in the same module - i.e. `let age: vueNumber = '';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a declaration file, then remove `export` from `vue-number.d.ts`:

```
type vueNumber = number | '';
```

... and include the declaration file as a reference:

```
///<reference path="vue-number.d.ts"/>
let age: vueNumber = '';
```

Comment: Or better include it via tsconfig, then you don't need a "reference"

Comment: @AlekseyL. could you give us a little more information about how to include the type via tsconfig?

Comment: @flyingace have you tried to just include the typings in `files`? if that doesn't work for some reason have a look at `typeRoots` option https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types